# How to get sparse graph Laplacian matrix in python?

Tags: python, matlab, graph, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix `A` in csr_matrix format. `A` is the weighted adjacency matrix of an undirected graph and thus symmetric and nonnegative. I want to calculate its graph Lapalican.

I used to work with MATLAB, where the code is pretty simple:

```matlab
L = diag(sum(A,2)) - A   % or L=diag(sum(A))-A because A is symmetric
```

But how can we do it in Python? I am new to sparse matrices in Python. I can only come up with a quite ugly solution:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sps
L = sps.diags(np.reshape(np.array(A.sum(axis=1)), A.shape[0])) - A
```

Does anyone know a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how the [networkX library](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/_modules/networkx/linalg/laplacianmatrix.html#laplacian_matrix) does it for a sparse matrix A - very similar to your method with small improvements (keeping everything sparse):

```
n,m = A.shape
diags = A.sum(axis=1)
D = sps.spdiags(diags.flatten(), [0], m, n, format='csr')
D - A
```

Comment: Thanks. Using spdiags and flatten looks better.